# when I use USB drive, how can I achieve CACLS and ICALS functionality?

Tags: windows, cmd, directory, cacls

I need to create a directory, which is not having the functionality of a normal one. I used the CACLS and ICACLS commands to make the directory as Secured and undeletable to others. It was worked successfully when the directory present in my system (NTFS). I created a directory in my USB drive, I used the same command, the out put is **"The Cacls command can be run only on disk drives that use the NTFS file system."**  Is any command to achieve this concept when the directory was present in USB Drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the research, before execute the command **format your USB drive in NTFS file system**. Now this command work's well.